# Qwerty Keyboard in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, qwerty

I need a QWERTY keyboard using HTML buttons, which enters the typed info into a text field. I can put one together, but it seems that this must have been done before, and I hate to reinvent the wheel. Does anyone know where I could find code for something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you mentioned javascript in your tags; so what about this stylish keyboard:
[the article describing it](http://designshack.co.uk/tutorials/creating-a-virtual-jquery-keyboard) – and a [demo](http://www.designshack.co.uk/tutorialexamples/vkeyboard/).

Comment: Nice trickery... But as someone in the comments there pointed out, this is virtually useless against keyloggers -- if that was the intent of the question. Anyway, +1.